# QuartzCore - Adding Rounded Corners to a Polygon

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-core

I'm attempting to draw a translucent black rectangle with a triangle cut out of the center.

I have this working perfectly with the code below. However, I'd like to round the corners of the triangle.

I've tried a couple of different techniques for adding rounded corners such as setting CGContextSetLineCap for a stroke and by creating my path with quartz and using CGContextAddArcToPoint, but I've failed to get anything to work.

As I mentioned, the code below works for a triangle cutout. How can I round the corners of the triangle?

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height * .7);
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width*.8, rect.size.height*.5);

CGFloat firstPointX = (position.x - (size.width / 2));
CGFloat firstPointY = (position.y - (size.height));
CGPoint firstPoint = CGPointMake(firstPointX, firstPointY);

CGFloat secondPointX = position.x + (size.width / 2);
CGFloat secondPointY = position.y - (size.height);
CGPoint secondPoint = CGPointMake(secondPointX, secondPointY);


UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:position];
[path addLineToPoint:firstPoint];
[path moveToPoint:firstPoint];
[path addLineToPoint:secondPoint];
[path addLineToPoint:position];
[path closePath];

CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath);
CGContextEOClip(context);

UIColor *translucentColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, translucentColor.CGColor);

CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

EDIT: Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: OK - I've deleted my previous answer because I've tried it and can't seem to get it to work with clipping.  If you stroke the path the round line joins work fine.  And it's now 4am.  I'll have another attempt tomorrow.

Comment: have you tried CGContextAddArc?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use CGContextAddArc.  It draws part of a circle with a line leading up to it if necessary.  Here's the code to draw a rounded box that fills a UIView.  For a triangle you'd have 3 lines instead of 4.  Two on the top and one in the middle on the bottom. This is from a roundBoxView class I have:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect boxRect = self.bounds;

float bRadius = self.cornerRadius;
float shrink = self.strokeThickness/2;

CGContextBeginPath(context);

// instead of this gray you could later add options for other colors
CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 0.0f, self.backgroundOpacity);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(boxRect)+shrink + bRadius, CGRectGetMinY(boxRect)+shrink);

CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(boxRect)-shrink - bRadius, CGRectGetMinY(boxRect)+shrink + bRadius, bRadius, 3 * (float)M_PI / 2, 0, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(boxRect)-shrink - bRadius, CGRectGetMaxY(boxRect)-shrink - bRadius, bRadius, 0, (float)M_PI / 2, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(boxRect)+shrink + bRadius, CGRectGetMaxY(boxRect)-shrink - bRadius, bRadius, (float)M_PI / 2, (float)M_PI, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(boxRect)+shrink + bRadius, CGRectGetMinY(boxRect)+shrink + bRadius, bRadius, (float)M_PI, 3 * (float)M_PI / 2, 0);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Of course instead of the boxRect being the full bounds you could pass that to your method and draw it using whatever bounds you want.  To make it a triangle you would only have the 3 lines instead of two and you might have to do some math to figure out the start and end angles. On a box those angles are always 90 degrees (here given is icky radians) but on a triangle you'll either have to calc the angles on the fly or have a preset aspect ratio on the triangle so you can use preset start and stop angles.  In the example as pictured with 3 equal angles you'd do 120 degrees or M_PI / 1.5 sized steps.